# Mongoose query where with missing (or undefined) fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an issue that I have a messy MongoDB database with a revised Mongoose scheme.

I want to be able to query using the `where` command, but if the field is missing or `undefined` in any found record then Mongoose returns an error.

For instance:

```
  return this.find({personID: req.user._id})
  .where('rangeBefore').lt(time);
```

This returns an error because some records do not have `rangeBefore`.

What I want to achieve is that any record without the `rangeBefore` field is filtered out (i.e. it fails the `where` test).

I have tried prefixing with `exists` like this:

```
  return this.find({personID: req.user._id})
  .exists('rangeBefore').where('rangeBefore').lt(time);
```

but I still get an error.

Can anyone suggest a way to ignore records with `undefined` fields, rather than returning an error?

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "rangeBefore"

Comment: That error message typically means that your `time` variable is `undefined`.  A query like this will naturally ignore docs where `rangeBefore` doesn't exist.  What's the value of `time`?

Comment: You are quite correct - the problem was with 'time'. This is quite a relief - I was wondering if mongoose could not carry out a query when a field is absent from a particular record, but in fact it works fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you just want to modify your existing query:

```
return this.find({ personID: req.user._id, 
  rangeBefore: { $exists: true, $ne: null } //also check for nulls
})
.where('rangeBefore').lt(time);
```

Or you can use the callback approach too if it fits:

```
this.find({personID: req.user._id, 
  rangeBefore: { $exists: true, $ne: null, $lt: time } 
})
.exec(function(err, record) { });
```

Comment: This is the answer to my question, but I was barking up the wrong tree.  It was the `time` variable that had a problem, not the query.  Nevertheless, your query code does what is needed.  From testing it appears that a `$lt` query automatically rejects a record if the field does not exist, so the `$exists` is not necessary here.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this, which returns a promise:

```
find({rangeBefore: { $exists: 1, $lt: time } }).exec()
```

Or use a callback:

```
find({rangeBefore: { $exists: 1, $lt: time } }).exec(function(err, record){

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message of:

> Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "rangeBefore"

means that your `time` variable is `undefined`. A query like this will naturally ignore docs where `rangeBefore` doesn't exist.

So the problem is with your `time` variable, not your docs or query.